# trouble installing ubuntu on toshiba satellite L775

Tags: system-installation

i am trying to install ubuntu on an older toshiba satellite l775 that has had its hard drive completely wiped with no OS on it and when i go to install ubuntu i get an I/O error at about 30% or so it is an i3 processor and a 500 gb hard drive.

Comment: The HDD is defective.

Comment: IO error usually means hardware error (input output error on a device).  But which device is it?   Did you verify your download & write to ISO?  (this should ensure the IO error isn't on your install-media) or your hdd/sdd?  If it's your hdd/sdd I'd suggest checking your hardware (`smartctl` or like tool, `gnome-disks` etc before you attempt install of anything onto it). SMART data will query the drive itself about its health (from circuitry, most drives have it with only real-cheap devices not having it).

Comment: If you end up needing a new hard drive, I suggest getting a new SSD instead of HDD as SSD runs so much faster (like lightning) on Ubuntu and there is less chance of the disk failing because there is no disk involved.

Answer (score 1):

There is several solutions for this. You could try a USB install or take out the hard drive and put it in another system with a cd rom, floppy, USB internet connection.
If you can boot from USB your only problem is choosing a distribution. If the install fails **try the live option and check the HD for errors**. 
Create another USB to rule out a corrupt file or USB stick.
If it is the HD check in the BIOS if the settings for the HD are correct.

Comment: how do try the live option to check for disk errors

Comment: Boot Ubuntu from usb or cd (Without installing) and there is an option for running it live. Once arrived at the desktop you can use Disks to check the HD. Its slow but gets the job done.